System.Drawing.Common 8.0.0 missing - but its not
I have been getting the weirdest unhandled exception - (one of the green ones, not the yellow) - and its complaining about a missing file exception that it can't find System.Drawing.Common 8.0.0.0.
The fact is this is installed and referenced appropriately and I can't work it out.
My original code did call a function with reference to a BitmapImage object, but I have since removed this to eliminate issues with the Drawing dll - however EVEN after removing this code referencing a BitmapImage - it STILL complains about this missing file, it makes zero sense, I believe its a bit of a "red-herring" error and is to do with something else that is not 100% related and it's sending me off down a blind alley.
Can anyone think of what might be causing this error - and any ways I might go around resolving it.


Might be an assembly binding redirect problem. Check your myexe.config file for bindingRedirects, and that the version specified matches the actual file in your output folder.

I think you must target .net-6.0-windows.

Is the DLL actually making it into the published application? It could be referenced, but go missing during dotnet publish.

Can you uninstall the package?

It seems to be published in the debug folder and the version of the dll is correct.

My project is targeting .net-6.0-windows

I have uninstalled the Drawing package and re-installed it.

Are you using NuGet to install the package? If so, then this NuGetSolver utility may be of use (or it may not - but worth a try!)

I am using Nuget in Visual Studio

My project uses .net6 core.
I think I was missing the Windows Compatibility Pack from Nuget - which assists to make legacy packages like System.Drawing work properly in this .net6 environment.
